# Converting image to bytes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am using the below code for converting a png image  in local path(D:\CURR PROJECT\NewUIChanges\Htmlfile\round1.png)to bytes.I am getting a null execption ie)img stream is null.Plz hep me.

```
 Stream imgStream;
    imgStream =   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("NewUIChanges.Htmlfile.round1.png");
    byte[] data = new byte[(int)imgStream.Length];
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < data.Length)
    {
        int bytesRead = imgStream.Read(data, offset, data.Length - offset);
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
        {
            throw new EndOfStreamException("Stream wasn't as long as it claimed");
        }
        offset += bytesRead;
    }
```

Comment: Probably because `imgStream ` is null, and that's likely due to a bad path going in to `GetManifestResourceStream`.  Is the file added to the project as an *embedded resource*?  If you call `GetManifestResourceNames`, what does it tell you that path should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the build action of the image to Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 0):

This line generating a problem. imgStream is null.

```
 imgStream =   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("NewUIChanges.Htmlfile.round1.png");
```

Check your image path. Probably is wrong.